# Using iterators to simplify model in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I'm relatively new to automating processes with ArcGIS. The overall goal of the model is to first isolate the road network of a user input town/city from a state/provincial road network file and then ensure that none of the segments in the new town/city network are greater than 500m. The logic behind segmenting is as follows:

- Check if there are roads in the network over 500m
- Create a layer of only roads over 500m
- Split roads in the new layer in half
- Check new layer to see if there are any segments over 500m
- Repeat until there are no segments over 500m

After the loop is complete, all the layers created from the loop are recomposed into a single final output layer.

This is shown in the screenshot, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use iterators to achieve what I want. In place of the iterators I've simply copy and pasted the process several times. Could you help me reduce this segment of the model down into a single loop?

[image]